# Ionic modal- keep navbar/menu visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to put my page into a modal-slide up,that **keeps the menu bar static** (as in, when the modal opens, the menu/top bar does not slide up).

The modal slide's up- but where the nav-bar/menu bar should be is white. The space is created (with class="has-header") but it is white.

[image]

By clicking on the magnify glass, the modal is activated on this site- [click here](http://stashdapp.com/azure/ios/www/index.html#/cards). I unsuccessfully tried making a plunker ([here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ScnGyy2eAmGwcJ7XZ2Z?p=preview)).

Here is my code:

To open modal (in my .html)

```
<i class="ion-ios-search-strong" ng-click="refineevent()"></i>
```

Part of my js

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('app/components/stores/stores.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function(modal){$scope.modal = modal;});

$scope.refineevent = function(){$scope.modal.show();};

$scope.closeModal = function(){$scope.modal.hide();};


$scope.$on('modal.shown', function(){console.log('Modal is shown!');});

    }
```

And my modal.html file:

```
<ion-modal-view>
<ion-view name="stores"><ion-pane ng-controller="storesCtrl">

            <ion-content class="has-header">
  ...
        </ion-content>

</ion-view>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use `<ion-view>` inside `<ion-modal-view>`. Try removing it and using `<ion-header-bar>` between `<ion-modal-view>` and `<ion-content>`

Comment: I did this- and it still shows a blank white space where the menu should be. Using "z-index" with CSS I can make it visible- however it is not usable/click-able. It sits "underneath" the modal. Any ideas?

Comment: A modal lays over all other views, so you cannot use menu. If your intention is not to use the menu button then using ion header will suffice in  the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modals you will have to create the header. So...

```
<ion-modal-view>
<ion-header-bar>
    <button class="button button-clear icon ion-drag"></button>
    <h1 class="title">LOGO</h1>
    <button class="button button-clear icon ion-hanger"></button>
</ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```